# Get the Head revision from http to bundle version

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, svn

I need to get head revision, from local repository.
So I use:

```
svn update 'path' --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username here_username --password here_password
```

And it works! In console:

```
Updating 'path':
At revision 29.
```

How to get this 29 number?

Also I try:

```
REV=`/usr/bin/svnversion -nc 'path' | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/^[^:]*://;s/[A-Za-z]//'`
echo $REV
```

And the result is `23`

But it get last revision, but not head.

In version I saw [image]

Also I found:

```
REVISION = $(svn info -r HEAD 'http://login:password@url' | sed -n "/Revision/p" | sed "s/[^0-9]//g")
echo $REVISION
```

But I don't know why the authorization is failed.

So how I can get the head revision using `shell` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `path` in `svn up` is some node inside your Working Copy (and *it is*), you'll get not HEAD of repository as result, but *last-committed revision of this directory* in repository (HEAD *may be* later revision of commit on another path)
- Your `svnversion` invocation is, well, strange (i'm too lazy to dissect also sed) - if you want HEAD of **repository** and have clean Working Copy of it, easiest way is just `svnversion .` inside WC (`-n` is OK, if you want to get it into variable), not `-c` and relative path (revision is global)

Just compare results of my and your svnversion for such Working Copy

```
svn ls -v
      5 lazybadg              фев 07  2014 ./
      2 lazybadg              ноя 28  2013 branches/
      2 lazybadg          146 ноя 28  2013 readme.textile
      1 www-data              ноя 27  2013 tags/
      5 lazybadg              фев 07  2014 trunk/
```

As you can see (and will agree with me, yes?) HEAD of this WC|repo must be 5. But, your svnversions may give

```
svnversion -nc trunk
2:5

svnversion -nc branches
2
```

And my short `svnversion -n` in any tree of (clean) Working Copy

```
>svnversion -n
5
>cd branches
>svnversion -n
5
```

- For `svn info URL`

  - `-r HEAD` may be omitted (`HEAD is default revision`)
  - `--username here_username --password here_password` will work, and work better, than URL-encoded authorisation
  - <sub>not SVN-related</sub> Instead of two pipes to (terrible) sed, you can easy extract Revision value from `svn info` output with simple short awk `svn info ... | awk '/Revision/ { print $2 }'` (**TBT!!!**)

**Note**

For all version-labeling task I prefer do not reinvent the wheel, but use common well-known solutions, such as SubWCRev|SVNRev